# Could not find path for REST resource (Wildfly 22.0.0 deployment)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, wildfly, web-deployment

When I deploy my Web Application to Wildfly 22.0.0, I can't seem to find the path for my Rest resource:

```
Could not find resource for full path: http://127.0.0.1:8080/CourseManagementApplication/rest/api/assignments/list
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>impl.rest.application.RestApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**RestApplication.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

        classes.add(AssignmentResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

**AssignmentResource.java**

```
@Path("/assignments")
public class AssignmentResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response getAssignments() {
        return ........
    }
}
```

I thought the resource would be accessible through the URI [Root]/rest/api/assignments/list. I can't understand why this path doesn't work.

Comment: servlet-mapping and @ApplicationPath serve the same purpose. They are not used along side each other. The former takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems in this code:

1- As mentioned in the comment above, I shouldn't have used servlet-mapping and @ApplicationPath simultaneously. So I removed the **@ApplicationPath** anotation in **RestApplication.java**.

2- I wasn't aware that in order to use a url pattern different from `/*`, you should not only define it in the `server-mapping` but it is also necessary to add the `context-param` to the **web.xml**, like this

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

So the endpoint becomes correctly available in http://127.0.0.1:8080/CourseManagementApplication/rest/assignments/list